# Youtube Video not showing in a web page when embed using iframe?

Tags: html

I want to embed a Youtube video on my website. I have tried the following code but it does show the video or any controllers:

```
 <iframe width="400" height="300"
            src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z-QgsXkYqjc"
            frameborder="1"
            allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `src` to this:

`src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/z-QgsXkYqjc"`